# Vue.js и Uikit 3

Tags: vue.js, uikit

Был собран сайт с нескольками страницами на vue + uikit 3
В мобильной версии использую стандартный uikit off-canvas для меню.
Проблема в том что после открытия меню мобильного (off-canvas), off-canvas не прячиться, но переход на страницу совершен по нажатию на пункт меню.

В докумеентации Uikit написанно что можно закрыть скриптом вот этим "UIkit.offcanvas(element).hide();" как его подружить с vue.js ?

Написать метод в который вставить этот кусок кода не сработал(

https://getuikit.com/docs/offcanvas#off-canvas

**UPD:** Решение было найде. Оставил в ответах

Comment: А UIKit видит в методе? И element определен?

Comment: @Idushii Ответ был найден.

Comment: очевидно что бы не было минусов в рейтинге надо показывать код а не выкладывать ссылку на оф сайт хотя решение было найдено самостоятельно что и заслуживает похвалы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был найден.
Для того чтоб закрывался offcanvas, надо для ссылок добавить класс "uk-offcanvas-close" и потом css поправить вид и все работает. Это решение работает для UIkit + Vue.JS

```
<a href="#my-id" uk-toggle></a>

<!-- This is the off-canvas -->
<div id="my-id" uk-offcanvas>
    <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar">

        <button class="uk-offcanvas-close" type="button" uk-close></button>
        <ul>
           <li><a  to="/" class="uk-offcanvas-close" >Home page</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
</div>
```